# Firebase with reactjs permission error even permission granted for latest version

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Ahhh... as a title you can see these type of errors not often occurs but finally, I got with luck (don't know good or bad).

I am using the latest version of reactjs and firebase I have to configure my firebase account just copy pasted the code in my firebase.js file and then import in other file name index.js and try to run and guess what? It gives me the error. [image: here is console error]

but everything is fine. Let me show you the other things.

this is my firebase.js file

[image: configration file]

this is firebase setting

[image: firebase setting]

I did find the solution anywhere Maybe due to its newer version. Hope I will get rid of this soon but I have posted here for now.

Comment: you explained nicely lol

Comment: oh thanks dude hope I got the solution soon!

Comment: Please include your code and errors as text instead of images.

Comment: @AndréKool So why there is the option of images in the StackOverflow ask a question panel can you explain me this? All the code I have copy pasted you can check in your firebase account. I should post the code if I have edit that but i don't.

Comment: @Pardeep Adding images is for things that can only be added as an image ("my website looks like this in Firefox..."). Code and error-messages should be searchable and copy-paste-able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

the above rules for the firestore Beta, Just click on the drop down near data base you see like this: [image: drop down select]

Now select realtime database and go to rules write below rules there:

```
{
 security rules. */
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```